# Django queryset: Filter by reverse key and order by

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

How can I filter models of `Procedure` that have their last `Status` in '1' using `procedurestatus_set`.

```
class Procedure(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
    )

Class Status(models.Model)
    procedure = models.ForeignKey(
       Procedure,
    ) 

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
    )

Procedure.objects.filter(status__status='1')
```

In the example above, we can get `Procedure`s that have any
`Status` (`procedurestatus_set`) with `status` 1, but not those whose last `Status.status` is 1.

How can can I filter `Procedure` by verifying their last `Status`?

`Procedure.objects.filter(status__last__status='1')`

I'm using Django 1.9.

Comment: You don't have a status date here, so what is the 'last' status? Largest primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'last' means largest pk and you want to query for all `Procedure` instances whose last `Status` has `status==1`, postgres allows you the following:

```
last_statuses=Status.objects.filter(
    id__in=Status.objects.order_by('procedure_id', '-pk').distinct('procedure_id')
).filter(status=1)

procedures = Procedure.objects.filter(id__in=last_statuses.values('procedure_id'))
```

In order for the two Filters you need in the `Status` query not to be merged into one filter expression when the db is actually accessed (which django will do), you have to use this nested expression with `id__in`.

In the case at hand, the nested (inner) `order_by` filter groups `Status` by `procedure_id` and sorts them by descending `pk`, the `distinct` selects the first (largest `pk`) `Status` for each `Procedure` (Note: `distinct` with field arguments is only supported by Postgres with some [caveats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)). Then you can apply any other filter to the outer QuerySet.

The Django ORM should translate the whole into one query to the database.

Comment: Thank schwobaseggl, It works like a charm when using these two queries!